# how to create winsnmp service as windows client which will get snmp trap from server using c?

Tags: c++, c

I need to run windows service using WINsnmp and get snmp trap from server which is running in other system. can you help me to how to get this trap from Winsnmp servers and manipulate the data and also please share me the code that help me get more ideas about Winsnmp client service and how to get trap from server.